# xmppvCardTempModule myvCardTemp always returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm newly started in XMPP, I successfully updated my Vcard details to server. but when I try to fetch my Vcard details using xmppvCardTempModule method myvCardTemp its always returns nil, where as I can able to fetch other users vcards. using (XMPPvCardTemp *)vCardTempForJID:(XMPPJID *)jid shouldFetch:(BOOL)shouldFetch but this method also returns nil on myJId.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your XMPP server. Many XMPP implementations of server does not create a vCard on default. So you will need to create a vCard first for your user then if you fetch it in the future you will be able to see it. Hope that helped!